# How can I list all the tablespaces without getting into each instance?

Tags: db2, db2-luw, unix

I got around 98 instances in a single AIX server. I need to list all the tablespaces, their path and usage. Is there a way I can do that without getting into each instance, connecting into the database etc?

Comment: It would help to know your Db2 version. If you really have 90+ _instances_, each one of them would presumably require different credentials to obtain this information

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anywhere to test this at the moment, but either of these might work.

1. If you have `su` privileges to all instance owner users:

   ```
   db2ilist | while read inst; do su - $inst db2pd -alldbs -tablespaces; done
   ```
2. If you have sufficient privileges on all instances yourself:

   ```
   db2ilist | while read inst; do env DB2INSTANCE=$inst db2pd -alldbs -tablespaces; done
   ```